# TEC cold side temperature decreases, then increases rapidly

Tags: circuit-design, control, peltier, cooling

first post to this stack exchange.
Self teaching on TEC circuits. I bought a diymore TEC1-12706 12V 60W 6A. Note no heat sink installed on the TEC. To test the TEC I put together a series circuit as follows: battery 12V/8AH/10A max discharge, 100(Ohm) resistor and then the TEC. I placed a temp probe on the cold side, and another temp probe to measure ambient air temp.
First run went ok. Connected the positive battery lead and the TEC cold side temp decreased and stabilized to about 77deg(F) compared to ambient air temp of 80deg(F).
Second run, I desired to see if I could get a lower temp out of the TEC. So I removed the 100(Ohm) resistor. I connected the positive battery lead, and the TEC cold side temp immediately started to decrease, in about 6sec reaching about 65deg(F). Then I noticed the  TEC cold side temp started to increase. After several seconds the temp climbed past 100deg(F) and by the time I disconnected the battery, the TEC cold side temp had reached about 130deg(F).
I decided stand down since obviously I'm doing something wrong. I guess my first question is what was happening in the TEC to produce this temperature reversal?

My second question is do I need to think more carefully about the circuit design for a TEC? Do I need a some type of voltage or current regulator inline between the battery and the TEC? Maybe I should install a heat sink on the hot side before any further experimentation? Any suggestions on a good TEC cooling circuit welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: My understanding is that you can't let it overheat or it gets damaged which means you need to heatsink it properly. People always seem to worry about the cold side and measure how cold it gets but never pay attention to the hot side.

Comment: Maybe you should install a heat sink on the hot side before any further experimentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peltier units are extremely inefficient.  This means that for every watt of heat you move, you generate several more watts of heat in the unit.

The hot and cold side are physically coupled together.  Heat can migrate through the substrate.

Because of the above, you will never get the cold side more than about 30 F below the temperature of the hot side.  When you try, you end up generating so much heat within the unit that you will warm the cold side.

This is a very common pitfall that people new to TECs run into.  What you need to do is cool the hot side.  This often takes the form of a heatsink and fan.

Due to the inefficiency, you will never be able to move a large amount of heat uphill.

As for the driving circuitry, you typically want a current-controlled drive.  Lots of designs use PWM on a voltage source, but this is even less effecient.

Comment: To the drive-by downvoter:  A quick comment on how this answer could be improved would be appreciated.  It would help both me and the community.

Comment: Following Evildemonic's suggestion I did a search for "TEC current controlled circuit" and found this really good [link] (https://www.laserdiodecontrol.com/tec-controller-basics) introduction on TEC circuits. Not endorsing any particular organization. Its simply a well written article at a level a novice (like me) can follow.